# Como estilizar apenas um trecho de um texto?

Tags: html, css

Quero saber como posso ter um resultado como esse no meu texto:

[image: screenshot mostrando apenas uma parte de um parágrafo com cor diferente]

Quero destacar certo trecho e por em negrito.

`<p> A ferramenta é 100% online, desenvolvida com as mais modernas tecnologias </p>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize um span e uma classe CSS:

```css
.destaque {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #009933;
}
```

```html
<p>A <span class="destaque">ferramenta é 100% online</span>, desenvolvida com as mais modernas tecnologias.</p>
```

Ou o estilo diretamente na tag (não recomendado):

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;  color: #009933;">ferramenta é 100% online</span>
```

Comment: Valeu, Marcus! Mas tem uma maneira de passar isso direto lá no span? Sem usar uma classe CSS...

Comment: `<span style="font-weight: bold;  color: #009933;">ferramenta é 100% online</span>`

Comment: Muito obrigado! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a tag Mark do html5 e personalizar sua cor, a tag mark  é usada para colocar destaque em um trecho e ajudar com SEO

```
<style>
mark {
background-color:#009933; 
font-weight: bold; 
}
</style>
```